# How to solve Photoshop portable crash in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, wine, photoshop

I downloaded ***Photoshop CS5 portable 32-bit version*** to run it on ***Ubuntu 16.04*** with ***Wine***. The program starts fine, but when I try to open an image or make a new file, it crashes. This is the error message:

[image: error screenshot]

Does anyone know how should I fix it?

**NOTE:** I installed Wine by just this line of code:

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

and didn't do any of the things mentioned in this [link](https://www.wikihow.com/Install-Wine-on-Ubuntu). Can that cause the problem?

The contents of “show details”:

```
Unhandled exception: 0xc06d007e in 32-bit code (0x7b83935c).
Register dump:
 CS:0023 SS:002b DS:002b ES:002b FS:0063 GS:006b
 EIP:7b83935c ESP:0033d024 EBP:0033d0a8 EFLAGS:00000216(   - --  I   -A-P- )
 EAX:7b82694d EBX:0033d0d8 ECX:0033d050 EDX:0033d128
 ESI:00000000 EDI:00000000
Stack dump:
0x0033d024:  00160014 7ffd8c00 0e2fa500 0bf28d00
0x0033d034:  7bc36796 0033d060 c06d007e 00000000
0x0033d044:  00000000 7b83935c 00000001 0033d0d8
0x0033d054:  00000000 0033d088 7b8546f6 7ffd8c00
0x0033d064:  00000000 00000000 7bc48f00 103a2c08
0x0033d074:  7b8546cc 0033d0a0 7b8ae000 0bf6e364
Backtrace:
=>0 0x7b83935c in kernel32 (+0x2935c) (0x0033d0a8)
  1 0x0be7a29a in cooltype (+0x1aa299) (0x0033d11c)
  2 0x0be776c3 in cooltype (+0x1a76c2) (0x0033d168)
  3 0x0bd2c2ad in cooltype (+0x5c2ac) (0x0033d7e0)
  4 0x0bdd2d2c in cooltype (+0x102d2b) (0x0033dbe4)
  5 0x0bd841d6 in cooltype (+0xb41d5) (0x0033dc54)
  6 0x0be63750 in cooltype (+0x19374f) (0x0033dd00)
  7 0x018cede6 in photoshop (+0x14cede5) (0x0033dd5c)
  8 0x017ae005 in photoshop (+0x13ae004) (0x0033dff8)
  9 0x01751c80 in photoshop (+0x1351c7f) (0x0033e064)
  10 0x016d4e06 in photoshop (+0x12d4e05) (0x0033e07c)
  11 0x016d7a6d in photoshop (+0x12d7a6c) (0x0033e1f8)
  12 0x0114dd5d in photoshop (+0xd4dd5c) (0x0033e310)
  13 0x011840ba in photoshop (+0xd840b9) (0x0033e3e4)
  14 0x01187dac in photoshop (+0xd87dab) (0x0033e450)
  15 0x01178878 in photoshop (+0xd78877) (0x0033e480)
  16 0x01178df4 in photoshop (+0xd78df3) (0x0033e4a8)
  17 0x00b7e70c in photoshop (+0x77e70b) (0x0033e4dc)
  18 0x007b4052 in photoshop (+0x3b4051) (0x0033e598)
  19 0x007b48ec in photoshop (+0x3b48eb) (0x0033e5ac)
  20 0x007b7008 in photoshop (+0x3b7007) (0x0033e5ec)
  21 0x00cd437f in photoshop (+0x8d437e) (0x0033e62c)
  22 0x00cd4501 in photoshop (+0x8d4500) (0x0033e654)
  23 0x0150f36d in photoshop (+0x110f36c) (0x0033e6d4)
  24 0x0150f36d in photoshop (+0x110f36c) (0x0033e754)
  25 0x015011e0 in photoshop (+0x11011df) (0x0033e768)
  26 0x00c9ccf0 in photoshop (+0x89ccef) (0x0033e77c)
  27 0x0150f36d in photoshop (+0x110f36c) (0x0033e7fc)
  28 0x0150f36d in photoshop (+0x110f36c) (0x0033e87c)
  29 0x0150f36d in photoshop (+0x110f36c) (0x0033e8fc)
  30 0x0150f36d in photoshop (+0x110f36c) (0x0033e97c)
  31 0x0150f36d in photoshop (+0x110f36c) (0x0033e9fc)
  32 0x015957a5 in photoshop (+0x11957a4) (0x0033ea54)
  33 0x006afb26 in photoshop (+0x2afb25) (0x0033ea68)
  34 0x01505815 in photoshop (+0x1105814) (0x0033ea7c)
  35 0x01505832 in photoshop (+0x1105831) (0x0033ea88)
  36 0x006b096a in photoshop (+0x2b0969) (0x0033ea9c)
  37 0x006a2503 in photoshop (+0x2a2502) (0x0033ead0)
  38 0x006afd0d in photoshop (+0x2afd0c) (0x0033eae8)
  39 0x006ac243 in photoshop (+0x2ac242) (0x0033eb14)
  40 0x006ac446 in photoshop (+0x2ac445) (0x0033eb34)
  41 0x0072f250 in photoshop (+0x32f24f) (0x0033eb54)
  42 0x0072f77b in photoshop (+0x32f77a) (0x0033ebb0)
  43 0x00731737 in photoshop (+0x331736) (0x0033ebe4)
  44 0x0351c132 in adobeowl (+0x1c131) (0x0033ec20)
  45 0x0351c04a in adobeowl (+0x1c049) (0x0033ec78)
  46 0x03520f9d in adobeowl (+0x20f9c) (0x0033ecb8)
  47 0x0351f638 in adobeowl (+0x1f637) (0x0033ecd0)
  48 0x03583ca9 in adobeowl (+0x83ca8) (0x0033ed08)
0x7b83935c: addl    $12,%esp
Modules:
Module  Address         Debug info  Name (205 modules)
PE    340000-  39a000   Deferred        cggl
PE    3a0000-  3a9000   Deferred        adbeape
PE    3b0000-  3ee000   Deferred        ahclient
PE    3f0000-  3f2000   Deferred        psart
PE    400000- 3452000   Export          photoshop
PE   3460000- 34f1000   Deferred        sccore
PE   3500000- 3676000   Export          adobeowl
PE   3680000- 3727000   Deferred        axedomcore
PE   3730000- 3bac000   Deferred        mps
PE   3bb0000- 3cb8000   Deferred        plugplug
PE   3cc0000- 3ce5000   Deferred        tbb
PE   43d0000- 43e3000   Deferred        tbbmalloc
PE   4c30000- 4df5000   Deferred        adobelinguistic
PE   4e00000- 4f93000   Deferred        photoshop
PE   4fa0000- 51e0000   Deferred        psviews
PE   5c40000- 5dfe000   Deferred        amtlib
PE   6890000- 68dc000   Deferred        logsession
PE   68f0000- 68fd000   Deferred        fastcore.8bx
PE   6900000- 690e000   Deferred        plugin
PE   6910000- 693c000   Deferred        axe8sharedexpat
PE   6950000- 69c9000   Deferred        aif_core
PE   6a20000- 6a95000   Deferred        multiprocessor support.8bx
PE   7f30000- 7f7a000   Deferred        adobexmp
PE   8160000- 837f000   Deferred        aif_ogl
PE   8980000- 8a30000   Deferred        scriptuiflex
PE   8b80000- 8c32000   Deferred        mmxcore.8bx
PE   8c40000- 9019000   Deferred        libmmd
PE   9020000- 972d000   Deferred        svml_dispmd
PE   9c50000- a256000   Deferred        dicom.8bi
PE   af80000- afcd000   Deferred        bib
PE   b0e0000- b121000   Deferred        bibutils
PE   b240000- b424000   Deferred        ace
PE   b840000- bbbf000   Deferred        agm
PE   bcd0000- bfbc000   Export          cooltype
PE   f2e0000- f50b000   Deferred        scriptingsupport.8li
PE  10000000-100a4000   Deferred        extendscript
PE  2bcb0000-2bde4000   Deferred        wrservices
PE  4fad0000-50ffe000   Deferred        camera raw.8bi
PE  6a000000-6a63a000   Deferred        cg
PE  78050000-780b9000   Deferred        msvcp100
PE  78aa0000-78b5f000   Deferred        msvcr100
ELF 7b800000-7ba54000   Dwarf           kernel32<elf>
  \-PE  7b810000-7ba54000   \               kernel32
ELF 7bc00000-7bcda000   Deferred        ntdll<elf>
  \-PE  7bc10000-7bcda000   \               ntdll
ELF 7bf00000-7bf04000   Deferred        <wine-loader>
ELF 7d23d000-7d272000   Deferred        uxtheme<elf>
  \-PE  7d240000-7d272000   \               uxtheme
ELF 7d272000-7d288000   Deferred        libgpg-error.so.0
ELF 7d288000-7d2fd000   Deferred        libpcre.so.3
ELF 7d2fd000-7d31a000   Deferred        libgcc_s.so.1
ELF 7d31a000-7d3c9000   Deferred        libgcrypt.so.20
ELF 7d3c9000-7d3ef000   Deferred        liblzma.so.5
ELF 7d3ef000-7d3f8000   Deferred        librt.so.1
ELF 7d3f8000-7d41e000   Deferred        libselinux.so.1
ELF 7d41e000-7d4ac000   Deferred        libsystemd.so.0
ELF 7d4ac000-7d4b5000   Deferred        libffi.so.6
ELF 7d4b5000-7d4ce000   Deferred        libresolv.so.2
ELF 7d4ce000-7d528000   Deferred        libdbus-1.so.3
ELF 7d528000-7d5b4000   Deferred        libgmp.so.10
ELF 7d5b4000-7d5e9000   Deferred        libhogweed.so.4
ELF 7d5e9000-7d626000   Deferred        libnettle.so.6
ELF 7d626000-7d63b000   Deferred        libtasn1.so.6
ELF 7d63b000-7d66f000   Deferred        libidn.so.11
ELF 7d66f000-7d6d0000   Deferred        libp11-kit.so.0
ELF 7d6d0000-7d6dd000   Deferred        libkrb5support.so.0
ELF 7d6dd000-7d70e000   Deferred        libk5crypto.so.3
ELF 7d70e000-7d7e4000   Deferred        libkrb5.so.3
ELF 7d7e4000-7d7f8000   Deferred        libavahi-client.so.3
ELF 7d7f8000-7d950000   Deferred        libgnutls.so.30
ELF 7d950000-7d9a2000   Deferred        libgssapi_krb5.so.2
ELF 7d9a2000-7da29000   Deferred        libcups.so.2
ELF 7da47000-7da4e000   Deferred        libxfixes.so.3
ELF 7da4e000-7da5a000   Deferred        libxcursor.so.1
ELF 7da5a000-7da6d000   Deferred        libxi.so.6
ELF 7da6d000-7da71000   Deferred        libxcomposite.so.1
ELF 7da71000-7da7e000   Deferred        libxrandr.so.2
ELF 7da7e000-7da8a000   Deferred        libxrender.so.1
ELF 7da8a000-7da91000   Deferred        libxxf86vm.so.1
ELF 7da91000-7da95000   Deferred        libxinerama.so.1
ELF 7da95000-7da9c000   Deferred        libxdmcp.so.6
ELF 7da9c000-7daa0000   Deferred        libxau.so.6
ELF 7daa0000-7dac6000   Deferred        libxcb.so.1
ELF 7dac6000-7dc11000   Deferred        libx11.so.6
ELF 7dc11000-7dc26000   Deferred        libxext.so.6
ELF 7dc2a000-7dc2f000   Deferred        libkeyutils.so.1
ELF 7dc2f000-7dc34000   Deferred        libcom_err.so.2
ELF 7dc34000-7dc42000   Deferred        libavahi-common.so.3
ELF 7dc44000-7dcd1000   Deferred        winex11<elf>
  \-PE  7dc50000-7dcd1000   \               winex11
ELF 7dd47000-7dd71000   Deferred        libexpat.so.1
ELF 7dd71000-7ddba000   Deferred        libfontconfig.so.1
ELF 7ddba000-7dde5000   Deferred        libpng12.so.0
ELF 7dde5000-7de95000   Deferred        libfreetype.so.6
ELF 7de95000-7debc000   Deferred        mpr<elf>
  \-PE  7dea0000-7debc000   \               mpr
ELF 7debc000-7ded7000   Deferred        libz.so.1
ELF 7ded7000-7df4e000   Deferred        wininet<elf>
  \-PE  7dee0000-7df4e000   \               wininet
ELF 7df4e000-7e083000   Deferred        msvcp90<elf>
  \-PE  7df90000-7e083000   \               msvcp90
ELF 7e083000-7e132000   Deferred        msvcrt<elf>
  \-PE  7e0a0000-7e132000   \               msvcrt
ELF 7e132000-7e15f000   Deferred        msvcr90<elf>
  \-PE  7e140000-7e15f000   \               msvcr90
ELF 7e15f000-7e254000   Deferred        comctl32<elf>
  \-PE  7e170000-7e254000   \               comctl32
ELF 7e254000-7e47d000   Deferred        shell32<elf>
  \-PE  7e260000-7e47d000   \               shell32
ELF 7e47d000-7e4b9000   Deferred        winspool<elf>
  \-PE  7e480000-7e4b9000   \               winspool
ELF 7e4b9000-7e4ed000   Deferred        ws2_32<elf>
  \-PE  7e4c0000-7e4ed000   \               ws2_32
ELF 7e4ed000-7e60b000   Deferred        opengl32<elf>
  \-PE  7e510000-7e60b000   \               opengl32
ELF 7e60b000-7e66b000   Deferred        liblcms2.so.2
ELF 7e689000-7e6a9000   Deferred        mscms<elf>
  \-PE  7e690000-7e6a9000   \               mscms
ELF 7e6a9000-7e725000   Deferred        rpcrt4<elf>
  \-PE  7e6b0000-7e725000   \               rpcrt4
ELF 7e725000-7e854000   Deferred        ole32<elf>
  \-PE  7e740000-7e854000   \               ole32
ELF 7e854000-7e981000   Deferred        oleaut32<elf>
  \-PE  7e870000-7e981000   \               oleaut32
ELF 7e981000-7e9ed000   Deferred        advapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7e990000-7e9ed000   \               advapi32
ELF 7e9ed000-7eb04000   Deferred        gdi32<elf>
  \-PE  7ea00000-7eb04000   \               gdi32
ELF 7eb04000-7ec52000   Deferred        user32<elf>
  \-PE  7eb20000-7ec52000   \               user32
ELF 7ec52000-7ecc8000   Deferred        shlwapi<elf>
  \-PE  7ec60000-7ecc8000   \               shlwapi
ELF 7ecc8000-7ed52000   Deferred        gdiplus<elf>
  \-PE  7ece0000-7ed52000   \               gdiplus
ELF 7ed52000-7ed65000   Deferred        libnss_files.so.2
ELF 7ed65000-7ed72000   Deferred        libnss_nis.so.2
ELF 7ed72000-7ed8d000   Deferred        libnsl.so.1
ELF 7ef8d000-7efe2000   Deferred        libm.so.6
ELF 7efe7000-7f000000   Deferred        version<elf>
  \-PE  7eff0000-7f000000   \               version
ELF f5262000-f5bff000   Deferred        i965_dri.so
ELF f6b4f000-f6c81000   Deferred        wined3d<elf>
  \-PE  f6b60000-f6c81000   \               wined3d
ELF f6c81000-f6ca7000   Deferred        dxgi<elf>
  \-PE  f6c90000-f6ca7000   \               dxgi
ELF f6ca7000-f6cd8000   Deferred        wbemprox<elf>
  \-PE  f6cb0000-f6cd8000   \               wbemprox
ELF f6cfa000-f6d1f000   Deferred        iphlpapi<elf>
  \-PE  f6d00000-f6d1f000   \               iphlpapi
ELF f6d1f000-f6d8b000   Deferred        setupapi<elf>
  \-PE  f6d30000-f6d8b000   \               setupapi
ELF f71a0000-f71d7000   Deferred        libtxc_dxtn.so
ELF f71fa000-f7206000   Deferred        libpciaccess.so.0
ELF f7206000-f7214000   Deferred        libdrm_radeon.so.1
ELF f7214000-f723b000   Deferred        libdrm_intel.so.1
ELF f723b000-f7256000   Deferred        libxcb-glx.so.0
ELF f7256000-f7274000   Deferred        libglapi.so.0
ELF f7274000-f72e4000   Deferred        libgl.so.1
ELF f72e4000-f735e000   Deferred        libglu.so.1
ELF f737c000-f7431000   Deferred        windowscodecs<elf>
  \-PE  f7390000-f7431000   \               windowscodecs
ELF f7431000-f74fe000   Deferred        crypt32<elf>
  \-PE  f7440000-f74fe000   \               crypt32
ELF f74fe000-f7619000   Deferred        actxprxy<elf>
  \-PE  f7520000-f7619000   \               actxprxy
ELF f7793000-f77a7000   Deferred        libdrm.so.2
ELF f77a7000-f77bf000   Deferred        glu32<elf>
  \-PE  f77b0000-f77bf000   \               glu32
ELF f77bf000-f7800000   Deferred        rsaenh<elf>
  \-PE  f77d0000-f7800000   \               rsaenh
ELF f7901000-f790b000   Deferred        libdrm_nouveau.so.2
ELF f790b000-f7911000   Deferred        libxcb-dri2.so.0
ELF f7911000-f7914000   Deferred        libx11-xcb.so.1
ELF f7914000-f792c000   Deferred        wtsapi32<elf>
  \-PE  f7920000-f792c000   \               wtsapi32
ELF f792c000-f796d000   Deferred        usp10<elf>
  \-PE  f7930000-f796d000   \               usp10
ELF f796d000-f7983000   Deferred        dwmapi<elf>
  \-PE  f7970000-f7983000   \               dwmapi
ELF f7983000-f79af000   Deferred        netapi32<elf>
  \-PE  f7990000-f79af000   \               netapi32
ELF f79af000-f79ca000   Deferred        wsock32<elf>
  \-PE  f79b0000-f79ca000   \               wsock32
ELF f79ec000-f7a00000   Deferred        msimg32<elf>
  \-PE  f79f0000-f7a00000   \               msimg32
ELF f7b02000-f7b06000   Deferred        libxdamage.so.1
ELF f7b06000-f7b09000   Deferred        libxshmfence.so.1
ELF f7b09000-f7b44000   Deferred        winhttp<elf>
  \-PE  f7b10000-f7b44000   \               winhttp
ELF f7b44000-f7b68000   Deferred        imm32<elf>
  \-PE  f7b50000-f7b68000   \               imm32
ELF f7b68000-f7b8c000   Deferred        sti<elf>
  \-PE  f7b70000-f7b8c000   \               sti
ELF f7b8c000-f7ba0000   Deferred        psapi<elf>
  \-PE  f7b90000-f7ba0000   \               psapi
ELF f7bab000-f7bb0000   Deferred        libdl.so.2
ELF f7bb0000-f7d66000   Deferred        libc.so.6
ELF f7d66000-f7d83000   Deferred        libpthread.so.0
ELF f7d86000-f7d90000   Deferred        libnss_compat.so.2
ELF f7d90000-f7d98000   Deferred        libxcb-sync.so.1
ELF f7d98000-f7d9c000   Deferred        libxcb-present.so.0
ELF f7d9c000-f7da0000   Deferred        libxcb-dri3.so.0
ELF f7da1000-f7f56000   Dwarf           libwine.so.1
ELF f7f57000-f7f7c000   Deferred        ld-linux.so.2
ELF f7f7f000-f7f80000   Deferred        [vdso].so
Threads:
process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
0000000e services.exe
    0000003a    0
    00000039    0
    00000038    0
    0000001d    0
    0000001b    0
    00000016    0
    00000014    0
    00000010    0
    0000000f    0
00000012 winedevice.exe
    0000001f    0
    00000018    0
    00000017    0
    00000013    0
00000019 plugplay.exe
    00000020    0
    0000001e    0
    0000001a    0
00000021 explorer.exe
    00000023    0
    00000022    0
00000024 PhotoshopCS6Portable.exe
    00000025    0
0000002a (D) C:\Program Files\Adobe Photoshop CS6 13.1.2 Extended Final Portable[www.Patoghu.com]32bit\App\PhotoshopCS6\Photoshop.exe
    00000081    0
    00000080    0
    0000007f    0
    0000007e    0
    0000007d    0
    0000007c    0
    0000007b    0
    0000007a    0
    00000079    0
    00000078    0
    00000077    0
    00000076    0
    00000075    0
    00000074    0
    00000073    0
    00000072    0
    00000071    0
    00000070    0
    0000006f    0
    0000006e    0
    0000006d    0
    0000006c    0
    0000006b    0
    0000006a    0
    00000069    0
    00000068    0
    0000003e    0
    00000040    0
    00000031    0
    00000067    0
    00000066    0
    00000065    0
    00000064    0
    00000063    0
    00000062    0
    00000061    0
    00000060    0
    0000005f    0
    0000005e    0
    0000005d    0
    0000005c    0
    0000005b    0
    0000005a    0
    00000059    0
    00000058    0
    00000057    0
    00000056    0
    00000055    0
    00000053    0
    00000052    0
    00000045    0
    00000041    0
    00000009    0
    00000046    0
    00000034    0
    0000001c    0
    00000029    0
    0000000d    0
    00000026    0
    00000047    0
    00000043    0
    00000030    0
    0000002f    0
    0000002e    0
    0000002d    0
    0000002c    0
    0000002b    0 <==
00000036 svchost.exe
    00000027    0
    0000000b    0
    00000044    0
    0000003f    0
    0000003d    0
    0000003c    0
    0000003b    0
    00000037    0
00000048 rpcss.exe
    00000054    0
    00000051    0
    00000050    0
    0000004f    0
    0000004e    0
    0000004d    0
    0000004c    0
    0000004a    0
    00000049    0
System information:
    Wine build: wine-1.6.2
    Platform: i386 (WOW64)
    Host system: Linux
    Host version: 4.13.0-39-generic
```

Comment: @Melebius I added the details

Comment: In the [winehq appdb](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=20158) (which you should always consult first when an application doesn't work with wine out of the box), in the comments section a user named "Storm Engineer" posted the necessary steps.